# Как работать с входными данными flatten нейросети tensorflow Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, искусственный-интеллект

Недавно начал изучать нейросети на tensorflow, и после того как сделал нейросеть по уроку начал делать свою. Я решил сделать нейронку играющую в 2048, но я не знаю как работать с входными данными. В качестве входных данных идет матрица поля в таком виде:

```
[[ 8 16 32  0]
 [ 2  8  4  0]
 [ 4  2  2  0]
 [ 2  0  0  0]]
```

Но tensorflow жалуется на такой тип поэтому я начал преобразовывать его в такой вид:

```
[8, 16, 32, 0, 2, 8, 4, 0, 4, 2, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0]
```

Но даже в таком случае она жалуется не на те данные. Что делать?
Вот сами параметры нейронки:

```
model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(4, 4)),
    keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.Dense(4, activation='softmax')
])
```

Comment: Тип элементов матрицы смените с `int` на `float`.

Comment: ошибка осталась. Матрица изменилась в нечто такое: '[[0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 2. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [4. 0. 0. 0.]]'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flatten ждёт на вход данные в форме (количество образцов(длина батча), 4, 4), а вы передаёте просто (4, 4)

Попробуйте изменить форму:

```
input_data = np.array([[ 8, 16, 32, 0],
                       [ 2,  8,  4, 0],
                       [ 4,  2,  2, 0],
                       [ 2,  0,  0, 0]])

input_data = input_data.reshape((1, 4, 4))
```

Comment: не сработало, та же ошибка

Comment: Я просмотрел внимательнее ошибку, и в нем говорилось что можно вставлять np.array: ValueError: Failed to find data adapter that can handle input: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>, <class 'int'>. Ну как вы видите это тоже не помогло